# Secure point transaction for contest using SSL

Tags: security, rest, ssl, encryption

I am working with an online contest. We use native apps communicating with server using SSL. We generate usertokens through third party service that needs to be shipped in the header with the request.

So when a user is sending a new local game result from his/her phone to the server using SSL and token, how can we secure this? We need something more to make sure a hacker cannot send multiple point requests to the server.

- Can we generate special tokens for the transaction?
- Is it possible to hide information from hackers as long as the client is sending the request through SSL?

Comment: Is the hacker the user who can reverse engineer your application and has root on the end-point device? In that case you face the usual impossible DRM problem.

Comment: Well to be precise. The app is running on iPhone with iOS. You may assume a hacker with jailbroken phone can install anything as the user gets root. Also SSL certificates for a proxy such as Fiddler would be for Windows. This way a user could decrypt all SSL traffic and repeat and modify the SSL calls to server. Agree? So yes it would also be possible to reverse engineer the code. So what way is it then to secure traffic? Will it help to obfuscate the data or just slow down the hacking?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we generate special tokens for the transaction?

You can, but so can the attacker.

> Is it possible to hide information from hackers as long as the client is sending the request through SSL?

No. Usually, the solution to the problem is to put sensitive code and data on a server you control, and not a computer the attacker controls. That means the player must play remotely to keep the code and data out of the attacker's hands.

> So when a user is sending a new local game result from his/her phone to the server using SSL and token, how can we secure this?

Well, diversification might help. That is, instead of providing points when the server receives {Token, Point Request}, have the server monitor the player to ensure there is an interactive player who is making expected progress. That is, turn the simple `boolean` event {Token, Point Request} into an aggregation of decisions.